# GFortran: Not passing arrays between f03 and f90?

Tags: arrays, fortran, fft, fortran90, gfortran

I am a novice in Fortran programming but I have started using code::blocks with Fortran plugin.

I am trying to pass variables between my code (f03) and fftsg.f (code from
http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~ooura/fft.html) to calculate fft.

fftsg.f contains a subroutine called rdft (real discrete Fourier transform) that I try to use to calculate a fft of an input signal.

My code looks like:

```
program hello
  use fftsg ! module containing all of the code in fftsg.f
  implicit none
  integer :: i
  integer,parameter ::  n=1024                           ! size of the input / output
  real(8), dimension(n,2) :: curve1
  real(8), dimension(0:n-1)   :: curvefft                ! data -> rdft -> fft 
  integer :: ip(0:2+2**(int(log(n/2+0.5)/log(2.0))/2))   ! size specified in fftsg.f
  real(8) ::  w(0:n/2-1)                                 ! size specified in fftsg.f
  integer   ::  N_fft,isgn                               ! variables specified fftsg.f
  N_fft = 2*n
  curve1(:,1) = (/(i*0.001D0,i=0,n-1)/)                  ! x-axis
  curve1(:,2) = sin(40*curve1(:,1))*curve1(:,1)**2       ! sine curve
  curvefft(0:n-1) = curve1(:,2)                          ! input/output to rdft
  ip(0) = 0
  isgn = 1
  call rdft(N_fft,isgn,curvefft,ip,w)
end program
```

The program compiles without errors or warnings (with fftsg.f in the same project in code::blocks but error occurs when running.

Debugging shows that the scalars (`N_fft, isgn`) both carry their values over to `rdft`, but none of the values in the arrays (`curvefft, ip, w`) are passed along (they only appear as an array with size = 1 and the value is incorrect).

The `fftsg` module looks (compacted) like this:

```
module fftsg
contains
  subroutine rdft(n, isgn, a, ip, w)
    integer n, isgn, ip(0 : *), nw, nc
    real*8 a(0 : n - 1), w(0 : *), xi
    ...
  end
end module fftsg
```

Is there someone who could help? What is going wrong? Is it something with combining f03 and f90 code?

I am not sure I fully understand the code in fftsg but if I could have the correct arrays passed to fftsg, it could be a start...

So any help with that is much appreciated!

Comment: try being consistent with use of `real*8` vs. `real(8)`.  Like to see `implicit none` in the subroutine as well.

Comment: Two of the array dummy arguments in `rdft` are assumed size.  Can you show how your debugging suggests that they are of size 1?

Comment: Show us your data from the debugging, quite possibly you just interpret them wrong. The assumed size arguments (*) do not pass the array size with them.

Comment: Thank you for all help, I found that the "watches" window in code::blocks didn't show the values for the arrays (maybe just the memory address of the first element - and therefore size 1???) but the values, when printed, were correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subroutine rdft() seems to use a(0:n-1) according to the declaration

```
subroutine rdft(n, isgn, a, ip, w)
integer n, isgn, ip(0 : *), nw, nc
real*8 a(0 : n - 1), w(0 : *), xi
```

but the actual arguments seem inconsistent because N_fft is 2*size(curvefft).

```
integer,parameter ::  n=1024
real(8), dimension(0:n-1)   :: curvefft
integer   ::  N_fft,isgn
N_fft = 2*n
call rdft(N_fft,isgn,curvefft,ip,w)
```

Comment: Yes.. that was what was the problem. Thank you very much. (I confused it with the cdft subroutine in the same file that took the 2*N input instead of N... all good now.